# Doctrine (Silex) can't save data, no error

Tags: doctrine, silex, flush, persist

I'm having trouble trying to save data using doctrine. I don't understand why, but I can get data from the database, but I can't update/insert/delete.

I'm using the entityManager with the functions *perist()* and *flush()*.

I searched on google where the issue could be but I couldn't find anything.

```
function editPage($id, Request $request, Application $app) {
$data = array('id' => 0);
if ($id != 0) { // existing page
    $page = $app['em']->find('BLOG\\Models\\Page', $id); // get the page
    $data = array(
        'titre'     =>  $page->getTitle(),
        'slug'      =>  $page->getSlug(),
        'contenu'   =>  $page->getContent(),
        'id'        =>  $id
    );
}

$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data)
    ->setAction($app['url_generator']->generate('adminPageEdit', array('id' => $id)))
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('titre')
    ->add('slug')
    ->add('contenu', 'textarea')
    ->add('id', 'hidden')
    ->add('Envoyer', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();

    if($id != 0) { // existing page
        $page->setTitle($data['titre']);
        $page->setSlug($data['slug']);
        $page->setContent($data['contenu']);
    }
    else {
        $page = new Page(
            $data['titre'],
            $data['slug'],
            $data['contenu']
        );
    }

    $app['em']->persist($page);
    $app['em']->flush();

    $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('flash', 'Page validée!');
    return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('adminPagesList'));
}

    return $app['twig']->render('admin/editPage.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

When I try to use the form, there is absolutely no modification, but the I get the flash message, even if I had a *die();* before the redirect.

I hope someone can help me locate the problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the solution, it's simple, you can use the entityManager function find() just by using the var $app['em'], but you can't persist or flush with it. So the only thing to do, is to put this var in another var and it will work.
So the solution is:

```
$em = $app['em'];
$em->persist($something);
$em->flush();
```

Instead of directly using:
$app['em']->persist($something);